# Cloning and inserting tags using JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clone a `<div>` html tag and to insert it after the original one using JavaScript, but I can't fix it. Can you help me please ?

JavaScript code :

```
var divo = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var divc = divo.cloneNode(true);

document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(divc);
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8Kab6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the original element's `parentNode` function to get its parent, and then use `appendChild` to add it after.

```
var divo = document.getElementById('divTP1');
var divc = divo.cloneNode(true);

divo.parentNode.appendChild(divc);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kab6/4/)

Using `getElementsByTagName` isn't necessary since you have the reference to `divo` that you already need for the appending function.  calling `getElementsByTagName` again requires the browser to do another search through the DOM (albiet an easy one).

Also you don't need to use `getElementsByTagName` at all since you only want one element and it has an id.  Better to use `getElementById`.

This is the most efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Correct `getElementByTagName` as below, that will produce the desired result

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(divc);
```

Comment: @rzqr - Yeah just a typo. Accept it if it helped you.:-)

Answer (score 0):

The error with your original code was a missing "s" on the last line..

```
document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(divc);
```

should read

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(divc);
```